# GAE Go Json-RPC call example

Tags: google-app-engine, go, json-rpc

I'm trying to understand how to use Json-RPC calls in Google Go that would be used in a Google App Engine app. So far I understand that I somehow should call [rpc.Client.Dial](http://golang.org/pkg/rpc/#Dial), but I don't understand what the "network" and "address" parameters should be. Can anyone provide a sample, working code that demonstrates how to use Json-RPC in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already written an answer to your question on the go-nuts group, but for completeness, here it is:

> Go's jsonrpc package isn't compatible with GAE yet.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-go/uQ0cv0m9j0E/H3VCrFgEWvcJ

It's probably a good idea to read the full thread there, since it describes the limitations on GAE nicely and links to a patched library with lots of workarounds... The [issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2404) is already known, but has not been solved yet.

Comment: Hmm, pity that. Do you have any resources on using Json-RPC in non-GAE Go though?